# What are the best practices to pass variable to outer scope while using Promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I was working on a Scraper script using cheerio and puppeteer. Inside a cheerio each loop I wanted to resolve a redirected url field. Using Promise I can console log it but what is the best way to insert it in the metadata?

I am actually confused about the control flow also.

```
(async function main() {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: true,
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto('https://www.example.com/?q=async+urls&s=s');

    const content = await page.content();

    const $ = cheerio.load(content);

    var parsedResults = [];

    const fetchRedirect = async (url) => {
        try {
            let response = await doRequest(url);
          return response;
        } catch (err) {
          return false;
        }
      };

    const videoBlocks = $('td[itemprop="subjectOf"]').first().each(function (i, element) {


    const url = ($(this).find('a.title').attr('href'));

    const fetchUrl = fetchRedirect(url);
   
    // ** i can console log the redirected url **/
    fetchUrl.then(url => console.log(url));

        const title = ($(this).find('a.title').text());

        var metadata = {
            title
        };

        parsedResults.push(metadata);

    });

    function doRequest(url) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
          request(url, function (error, res, body) {
            if (!error) {
              resolve(getPathFromUrl(res.request.uri.href));
            } else {
              reject(error);
            }
          });
        });
      }

    function getPathFromUrl(url) {
        return url.split(/[?#]/)[0];
    
    }   
    console.log(parsedResults);
    await page.close()
    await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: You already use `async`/`await`. Why not here?

Answer (score 1):

```
//...............await!
const fetchUrl = await fetchRedirect(url);

// ** then instead that **/
// fetchUrl.then(url => console.log(url));
// just
console.log(fetchUrl)
const title = ($(this).find('a.title').text());

var metadata = {
    title
};

parsedResults.push(metadata);
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would go for a Node module. The code like this is hard to read as inside one function(main) you have declared multiple functions. It is upon your preference whether to apply OOP or functional programming there(the second is much more popular in Node environment but I prefer the first if I am going to create a functionality around a specific entity). Avoiding nesting and abstract functions(functions that you declare inside other functions) is crucial in creating a reusable and readable code.

Here it is a worked prototype(not tested). It makes a puppeteer instance reusable. The module exposes three methods: start, stop, crawlWeb

```
'use strict'

var browser;

async function crawlWeb(options) {
    // validate options and throw errors
    if (!options.url) {
        throw new Error('url is invalid');
    }

    if (!browser) {
        throw new Error('puppeteer is not started');
    }

    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto(optionsl.url);

    const content = await page.content();

    const $ = cheerio.load(content);

    const metas = extracMetadata($);

    for (let metadata of metas) {
        // you can verify if site is valid
        // you can use await
        try {
            await doRequest(metadata.url);
        }
        catch(err) {
            // do something if not valid
        }
    }

    return metas;
}

async function start(options) {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch(options);
}

async function stop() {
    if (!browser) {
        throw new Error('puppeteer is not started');
    }

    await page.close()
    await browser.close();

}

function extracMetadata($) {
    const metas = [];
    $('td[itemprop="subjectOf"]').first().each(function (i, element) {
        const url = ($(this).find('a.title').attr('href'));

        const title = ($(this).find('a.title').text());

        var metadata = {
            url,
            title
        };
        metas.push(metadata);
    });

    return metas;
}

function doRequest(url) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        request(url, function (error, res, body) {
            if (!error) {
                resolve(getPathFromUrl(res.request.uri.href));
            } else {
                reject(error);
            }
        });
    });
}

function getPathFromUrl(url) {
    return url.split(/[?#]/)[0];
}

module.exports = {
    crawlWeb,
    start,
    stop
};
```

Comment: I don't see how three methods that you have to call one after another are better than a simple single one. Also there's no OOP around?

Comment: @Bergi I already made it clear that nested functions decrease readability and can cause confusions. I chose functional programing in the end as I stated that this is widely used in node environment. I exposed three methods just to make it more reusable, instead I could have exposed just one(crawlWeb), but I wanted to give more control to the user by explicitly letting them to create, destroy a puppeteer browser.